How to add dynamic value in "data-row-num" by Jquery
I want to add (data-row-num="1",data-row-num="2",data-row-num="3") for my HTML table row.
Can someone please help me to do it like  ?
<table id="example" class="table table-striped first-table" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {  } );
});

  $("tr").each(function() {
    $("tr").attr("data-row-num",????); 
}); 
<script>


Loop over tbody tr using .each()
Use the function index parameter to provide value to data-row-num. Just take care that the index parameter starts with 0 so you need to add 1 into it each time.
So you need to modify your code like below:
$(function() {
  let table = new DataTable('#example');
  $("tbody tr").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).attr("data-row-num", i+1);
  });
});

Working snippet:


$(function() {
  let table = new DataTable('#example');
  $("tbody tr").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).attr("data-row-num", i+1);
  });
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped first-table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>




Ok! Can you also help me to know that how I can do these Data Tables without custom codes?

For the next step, you might like to revisit: jquery .each() => $("..").each((i, e) => $(this).attr("data-row-num", i));

@Siddharth I have modified my code based on the suggestion given by fdomn-m . You can use it as a better approach.
